# Python XArray subtract group mean from each dataarray

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm new to XArray and I'm trying to replicate the first block of code from this site in XArray (https://nirpyresearch.com/two-scatter-correction-techniques-nir-spectroscopy-python/)
but running into issues pretty early on.

I have a bunch of spectra (x and y vectors) from various samples, each with ~6 replicates. For each sample, I am trying to take the mean value of y at each x for the 6 replicates (together) and then subtract that vector of means from each of the individual replicates.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

# generate a dataset that looks similar to mine
ds_list = []
for i in [1,2,3]:
    for j in [1,2,3]:
        data = pd.DataFrame()
        data['x'] = np.arange(0, 3*np.pi, np.pi/6)
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, len(data['x']))
        data['y'] = np.sin(data['x'])+noise    
        dataset = data.set_index('x').to_xarray()
        dataset['System'] = f'y{i}_{j}'
        dataset['Sample'] = f'S{i}'
        dataset['Repeat'] = j
        ds_list.append(dataset)
ds = xr.concat(ds_list,dim='system')

# mean centre correction 
# centers each y around 0
# There should only be one y_average value
# per system
reference = ds.y.groupby('system').mean('x')
ds['y_mean'] = reference
ds['y_MCC'] = ds.y - reference

# get group means
# try to generate an average y vector for each Sample
# by grouping based on sample then averaging on system
# (really averaging the Repeats per system)
# so the array should still have
# one y per x value.
ds_grp_mns = ds.groupby('Sample').mean('system')
ds['y_corr'] = ds.y - ds_grp_mns.y
```

I've tried grouping by S#, but then I loose the replicate #, and can't add it back.
In my actual data I have dimensions of system=114 (all combos of S#_r#) by x=4000.
When I do a groupby().mean() it reduces dimensions to system=20 (all S#, no repeat information), x=4000

If I was using pandas I would be able to merge on S# and it would just duplicate the data for each r#, but XArray doesn't seem to like that since the dimensions aren't the same.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edited 11/25 to have min rep. example.

Comment: Can you also post the actual code you’re using? It’s tough to understand the structure of your data from these example lists, e.g. what is it that you’re grouping on? How is the data organized? Etc. a [mre] would be ideal but it would also be helpful if you just pasted the result of `print(ds)` so we can see what you’re working with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.